Retrieve value from known keys in simple nested Dictionary
I have a dictionary of Strings, like chapters or table of contents for an aircraft manual, like this:
let ataChapter: [[String:String]:Dictionary] = [
    ["21":"Air Conditioning"] : [
        "21-31":"Pressure control and monitoring",
        "21-51":"Pack flow control",
        "21-52":"Air cooling system",
        "21-55":"Emergency ram air inlet",
        "21-61":"Pack temperature control",
        "21-63":"Cockpit and cabin temperature control"],
    ["22":"Autoflight"] : [
        "22-01":"Overhead panel",
        "22-05":"FMA",
        "22-10":"A/P and F/D",
        "22-30":"Autothrust",
        "22-83":"FMGC"]
]

First level string pair is the chapter number and title, second level is each chapters code and its associated aircraft system. The dictionary will be quite long (this is just a few rows from it) but the format is the same so I don't see a reason for a struct, given its simple construction.
Now, I will have a known exact system code - something like "21-52-30A" and with that String I need to find and return:

the chapter name, e.g. "Air Conditioning" (value) from the top level value because the first 2 characters are 21, and

the system name, e.g. "Air cooling system" (value) from the second level because the first 4 characters are "21-52".


In other words, how do I match the key from the top level to the first 2 characters in my known string, and the key from the second level to the first 4 characters, and return their respective values?
I've done this so far:
for (keys, values) in ataChapter {
    for (item) in keys {
        print(item.value)
    }

    for (chapter) in values {
        print(chapter.value)
    }
}

I understand the concept of this simple loop, and with it I obviously get all the string values back but I'm a beginner at this stuff and can't figure out the matching part and return only the values matching the code in my String.

"so I don't see a reason for a struct, given its simple construction." The search would be easier imho.

Ok, I will look into it. Would you then have this list like a JSON file, create a struct and get the data from there? But is there a fairly straightforward way of doing this with my dictionary above?

What is your source for the dictionary? Is it hardcoded or do you download it or parse it from a file?

It's static and will always look the same, i.e. hardcoded

Do you have control over the way it's created? If yes, I'd simplify the structure. The key as dictionary is not a good idea in my opinion. Something like ["21": ["title": "Air Conditioning", "Items": ["31":"Pressure control and monitoring", "51":"Pack flow control"]] might be better...

If you insist on keeping your dictionary structure here is one way to do it
let chapterKey = "21"
let sectionKey = "21-52"

if let chapter = ataChapter.first(where: { $0.key[chapterKey] != nil }),
   let section = chapter.value.first(where: { $0.key == sectionKey }) {
    print(chapter.key.values.first!)
    print(section.key, section.value)
}


Air Conditioning
21-52 Air cooling system

If you don't like the forced unwrapping you could include
let chapterTitle = chapter.key.values.first,

in the if condition and use that variable instead.
Another solution is to use custom types instead of the dictionary construction. For example
struct Section {
    let key: String
    let title: String
}

struct Chapter {
    let key: String
    let title: String
    let sections: [Section]
}

and then have an array of Chapter. The search code would be pretty similar to what we already have but the advantage of a custom structure is that we can add functionality to it so for instance implement a subscript in Chapter:
subscript(_ sectionKey: String) -> Section? {
    sections.first(where: { $0.key == sectionKey })
}

If we also use a dictionary instead of an array with the chapter key as key
let chapters: [String: Chapter] = ...

then the search code could be simplified to
if let chapter = chapters[chapterKey], let section = chapter[sectionKey] {
    print(chapter.title)
    print(section.key, section.title)
}


I’ll try this out later and see if I can get it to work. I think I follow. Thank you!
